# Accessing member functions of multiple instances of a python class

Tags: python

I am looking for a code shortcut to access member functions of multiple instances of python class to avoid code redundancy. For instance,

```
class my_class:
    def __init__(self):
        ...

    def set_parameter(self):
        #sets some parameter
```

Now I create multiple instances of `my_class`

```
instance1 = my_class()
instance2 = my_class()
```

I would like to as if it is possible to access use `set_parameter` member function for both of the above instances in the same line of code?

Comment: why not just loop? `for instance in (inst1, inst2): instance.set_parameter()`?

Comment: Ah I see. And is there a similar loop method for creating multiple instances in the first place?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
class my_class:
    def __init__(self,txt):
        self.var=1
        self.txt=txt
    def prints(self):
        print(self.txt)

props = [1,4,5]
objects = [my_class(prop) for prop in props] # creates multiple objects here
for obj in objects:
    obj.prints()
```

output

```
1
4
5
```

Or You can also try this

```
class my_class:
    def __init__(self):
        self.var=1
    def setparameter(self,txt):
        self.txt=txt

objects = [my_class() for i in range(3)] # creates multiple objects here
for obj in objects:
    obj.setparameter(5)
```